# Реализовать плавное вращение объекта по направлению к курсору

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код.

```js
class rotationOfTheObjectTowardsTheCursor {

    constructor() {
        this.container = Object;
        this.gradient = Object;
        
        this.containerRect = Object;
        
        this.centerPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        this.angels = { actual: 0, target: 0 };
        
        this.init();
    }
    
    init() {
        this.container = document.querySelector('.project');
        this.gradient = document.querySelector('.gradient');
        
        this.onResize();
        window.onresize = (e) => this.onResize(e);
        
        window.onmousemove = (e) => this.onMouseMove(e);
        
        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
    }
    
    onResize() {
        this.containerRect = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();
        this.centerPosition = {
            x: this.containerRect.x + this.containerRect.width / 2,
            y: this.containerRect.y + this.containerRect.height / 2,
        };
    }
    
    onMouseMove(e) {
        const atan2 = Math.atan2(
            e.pageY - this.centerPosition.y,
            e.pageX - this.centerPosition.x
        );
        
        this.angels.target = atan2;
    }
    
    loop() {
        this.angels.actual = this.angleLerp(
            this.angels.actual,
            this.angels.target,
            0.1
        );
        this.gradient.style.background = `linear-gradient(${this.angels.actual}rad, #02d1f6, #eb03f9)`;

        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
    }
    
    angleLerp(a0, a1, t) {
        const max = Math.PI * 2;
        const da = (a1 - a0) % max;
        return a0 + (((2 * da) % max) - da) * t;
    }

}

new rotationOfTheObjectTowardsTheCursor();
```

```css
   .project {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39)), url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/11/20/42/mammals-3218028_960_720.jpg");
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

.project span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.project::after {
  content: '';
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, transform .35s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.project:hover::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.gradient {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, transform .35s;
  z-index: 1;
  height: calc(100% * 3);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #eb03f9, #02d1f6);
  position: absolute;
  /*width: 500px;
  top: -300px;
  left: -180px;
  height: 500px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.project:hover .gradient {
  transform: scaleY(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="project">
  <div id="gradient" class="gradient"></div>
  <span>Текст</span>
</div>
```

[`Ссылка`](https://codepen.io/Odiseu/pen/dyYxxZO)

Не могу сообразить, как сделать чтоб вращение немного опаздывало за курсором. Чтоб фон плавно подходил к курсору, а не просто мотылялся за курсором. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Надо весь код добавлять не посредственно в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Плавное вращение объекта по направлению к курсору

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/w7jc3r6p/4/)

```js
class rotationOfTheObjectTowardsTheCursor {

 constructor() {
  this.container = Object;
  this.gradient = Object;
  
  this.containerRect = Object;
  
  this.centerPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  this.angels = { actual: 0, target: 0 };
  
  this.init();
 }
 
 init() {
  this.container = document.querySelector('.project');
  this.gradient = document.querySelector('.gradient');
  
  this.onResize();
  window.onresize = (e) => this.onResize(e);
  
  window.onmousemove = (e) => this.onMouseMove(e);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
 }
 
 onResize() {
  this.containerRect = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();
  this.centerPosition = {
   x: this.containerRect.x + this.containerRect.width / 2,
   y: this.containerRect.y + this.containerRect.height / 2,
  };
 }
 
 onMouseMove(e) {
  const atan2 = Math.atan2(
   e.pageY - this.centerPosition.y,
   e.pageX - this.centerPosition.x
  );
  
  this.angels.target = atan2;
 }
 
 loop() {
  this.angels.actual = this.angleLerp(
   this.angels.actual,
   this.angels.target,
   0.1
  );
  this.gradient.style.background = `linear-gradient(${this.angels.actual}rad, #02d1f6, #eb03f9)`;

  requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
 }
 
 angleLerp(a0, a1, t) {
  const max = Math.PI * 2;
  const da = (a1 - a0) % max;
  return a0 + (((2 * da) % max) - da) * t;
 }

}

new rotationOfTheObjectTowardsTheCursor();
```

```css
.project {
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39)), url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/11/20/42/mammals-3218028_960_720.jpg");
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
}

.project span {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
 margin: auto;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.project::after {
 content: '';
 transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, transform .35s;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scaleY(0);
}

.project-1:hover::after {
 transform: scaleY(1);
 opacity: 1;
}

.gradient {
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, transform .35s;
 z-index: 1;
 height: calc(100% * 3);
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, #eb03f9, #02d1f6);
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.project:hover .gradient {
 transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
 <div id="gradient" class="gradient"></div>
 <span>Текст</span>
</div>
```

---

### Есть ещё вариант замкнуть анимацию.

```js
const project = document.querySelector('.project');
const gradient = document.querySelector('.gradient');

let isMouseEnter = false;

const loop = (t) => {
 if (!isMouseEnter) return;
 
 const angle = Math.cos(t / 500);
 gradient.style.background = `linear-gradient(${angle}rad, #02d1f6, #eb03f9)`;
 requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

project.onmouseenter = () => {
 isMouseEnter = true;
 requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
project.onmouseleave = () => isMouseEnter = false;
```

```css
.project {
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39)), url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/11/20/42/mammals-3218028_960_720.jpg");
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
}

.project span {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
 margin: auto;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.project::after {
 content: '';
 transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, transform .35s;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scaleY(0);
}

.project-1:hover::after {
 transform: scaleY(1);
 opacity: 1;
}

.gradient {
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, transform .35s;
 z-index: 1;
 height: calc(100% * 3);
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, #eb03f9, #02d1f6);
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.project:hover .gradient {
 transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
 <div id="gradient" class="gradient"></div>
 <span>Текст</span>
</div>
```

---

### Вариант с несколькими блоками

```js
class rotationOfTheObjectTowardsTheCursor {

 constructor(container, target, options = {}) {
  this.container = container;
  this.gradient = target;
    
    this.speed = Number(options['speed'] || 0.1);

    if (!container || !target)
        throw new Error('[rotationOfTheObjectTowardsTheCursor] Недостаточно аргументов.');

  this.containerRect = Object;
  
  this.centerPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  this.angels = { actual: 0, target: 0 };
  
  this.init();
 }
 
 init() {  
  this.onResize();
  window.onresize = (e) => this.onResize(e);
  
  this.container.onmousemove = (e) => this.onMouseMove(e);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
 }
 
 onResize() {
  this.containerRect = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();
  this.centerPosition = {
   x: this.containerRect.x + this.containerRect.width / 2,
   y: this.containerRect.y + this.containerRect.height / 2,
  };
 }
 
 onMouseMove(e) {
  const atan2 = Math.atan2(
   e.pageY - this.centerPosition.y,
   e.pageX - this.centerPosition.x
  );
  
  this.angels.target = atan2;
 }
 
 loop() {
  this.angels.actual = this.angleLerp(
   this.angels.actual,
   this.angels.target,
   this.speed
  );
  this.gradient.style.background = `linear-gradient(${this.angels.actual}rad, #02d1f6, #eb03f9)`;

  requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
 }
 
 angleLerp(a0, a1, t) {
  const max = Math.PI * 2;
  const da = (a1 - a0) % max;
  return a0 + (((2 * da) % max) - da) * t;
 }

}

const rotationContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.rotation-container');

rotationContainers.forEach((container, i) => {
    const target =  container.querySelector('.rotation-target');
    new rotationOfTheObjectTowardsTheCursor(container, target, { speed: 0.1 / (i + 1)});
});
```

```css
.project {
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39)), url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/11/20/42/mammals-3218028_960_720.jpg");
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
}

.project span {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 3;
 margin: auto;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.project::after {
 content: '';
 transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, transform .35s;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scaleY(0);
}

.project-1:hover::after {
 transform: scaleY(1);
 opacity: 1;
}

.gradient {
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, transform .35s;
 z-index: 1;
 height: calc(100% * 3);
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, #eb03f9, #02d1f6);
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.project:hover .gradient {
 transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="project rotation-container">
 <div id="gradient" class="gradient rotation-target"></div>
 <span>Текст</span>
</div>

<div class="project rotation-container">
 <div id="gradient" class="gradient rotation-target"></div>
 <span>Текст</span>
</div>

<div class="project rotation-container">
 <div id="gradient" class="gradient rotation-target"></div>
 <span>Текст</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.You are Monster of JavaScript. )

Comment: Добрый день еще раз. Столкнулся с проблемой. Первый пример. Хочу сделать на странице несколько одинаковых блоков с градиентом, но скрипт работает только в первом блоке. И как сделать, чтоб центра блока project и блока gradient всегда совпадали? Например если я хочу, сделать блок gradient (800px x 800px) больше блока project (100px x 200px) или другие размеры.

Comment: @OdiseuOdiseu сейчас сделаю для разных блоков. Насчёт второго вопроса не совсем понял.

Comment: @OdiseuOdiseu обновил ответ под несколько разных блоков.

Comment: Я изменил код в вопросе. Я увеличил длину и высоту блока gradient и убрал overflow: hidden; с блока project. При наведении на блок видно что блоки позиционируются относительно друг друга по верхнему левому углу. Можно чтоб они всегда совпадали центами?

Comment: @OdiseuOdiseu я не понимаю что вы хотите в итоге получить. Зачем-то вы добавили по 200% в ширину и высоту, что именно вы хотите получить? И я поправил вопрос и сделал помедленнее (с задержкой).

Comment: Спасибо я уже сделал. На такие простые вещи нужно и свои мозги включать. Еще раз Спасибо.